# Spark scala - parse json from dataframe column and return RDD with columns

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a sparkScala `RDD` that looks like this :

```
df.printSchema()

 |-- stock._id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- stock.value: string (nullable = true)
```

Second column of the `RDD` is a nested `JSON` :

```
[ { ""warehouse"" : ""Type1"" , ""amount"" : ""0.0"" }, { ""warehouse"" : ""Type1"" , ""amount"" : ""25.0"" }]
```

I need to generate an `RDD` that will contain the existing two columns but also the columns from the `JSON` like:

```
_id, value , warehouse , amount
```

I've tried to do it using custom functions, but I'm struggling to apply this function to my `RDD` and getting the needed result

`import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._`

`import org.json4s._`

```
 def extractWarehouses (value: String)  {
    val json = parse(value)
    for {
      JObject(warehouses) <- json
      JField("warehouse", JString(warehouse)) <- warehouses
      JField("amount", JDouble(amount)) <- warehouses
    } yield (warehouse, amount)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said `value` is a json array which is holding list of json objects, you need to explode it and get individual properties as columns something like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

val flattenedDF = df.select(functions.column("_id"), functions.explode(df("value")).as("value"))
val result = flattenedDF.select("_id", "value.warehouse", "value.amount")
result.printSchema()
```

Comment: Unforntunately this doesn't work I got the error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(value)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode sho uld be array or map type, not StringType;