# How to Convert a Column from String of json to Array in Apache Spark

Tags: json, string, apache-spark, schema, apache-spark-sql

The schema of data that read from hdfs is:

```
root
|-- id: string
|-- ext_json: string
```

while the data in ext_json is like:

```
[{'a':'1','b':'2'},{'a':'3','b':'4'}]
```

now I need to convert the data that schema is as follows:

```
root
|-- id: string
|-- ext_json: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- a: string
|    |    |-- b: string
```

How to do that?

Spark version is 2.0.1

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/42069295/1025328

Comment: @PrasadKhode yeah it's the same problem, but I got error: **data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not StringType**